# Random sample values in a matrix without replacement in R

Tags: r, matrix, sample, random

I've been searching on Stack Overflow for about 45 minutes now, so if indeed such question has been already posted - I apologize!

For example purposes, say I have a small matrix of 6 rows and 3 columns, out of which I need to randomly select values: 2 values from each column.

```
             Feb    Mar    Apr
Mt_Rainier   220.0  200.0  130.0
Vancouver    104.6  113.9  88.5
Neah_Bay     226.0  206.0  134.0
Portland     94.0   94.0   68.6
Olympic_Park 53.3   66.0   45.7
Orcas_Island 71.0   61.0   48.0
```

In other words, I need to select 2 locations for each month, but can't select the same location twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking `n` as the number of values to select per column, you can construct an index matrix with `n*ncol(m)` rows, where the row indexes are sampled without replacement from the available range of rows, and the column indexes are specified in regular order with `n` occurrences of each:

```
set.seed(1L);
m <- matrix(c(220.0,104.6,226.0,94.0,53.3,71.0,200.0,113.9,206.0,94.0,66.0,61.0,130.0,88.5,134.0,68.6,45.7,48.0),6,dimnames=list(c('Mt_Rainier','Vancouver','Neah_Bay','Portland','Olympic_Park','Orcas_Island'),c('Feb','Mar','Apr')));
n <- 2L;
im <- matrix(c(sample(nrow(m),n*ncol(m)),rep(seq_len(ncol(m)),each=n)),ncol=2L);
im;
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    1
## [2,]    6    1
## [3,]    3    2
## [4,]    4    2
## [5,]    1    3
## [6,]    5    3
m[im];
## [1] 104.6  71.0 206.0  94.0 130.0  45.7
rownames(m)[im[,1L]];
## [1] "Vancouver"    "Orcas_Island" "Neah_Bay"     "Portland"     "Mt_Rainier"   "Olympic_Park"
```

This ensures that each input column gets exactly `n` selections, and no input row will be selected more than once.

Comment: A question though. What if I had only 5 rows? Meaning that from 1 column I'll only be able to select 1 value, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

What (exactly) do you want the result to look like?  Do you want the *values* sampled from each column of the matrix?  If so, try:

```
c(                               ## collapse matrix result to a vector
   apply(m,MARGIN=2,FUN=sample,  ## sample from each column
     size=2,replace=FALSE        ## additional arguments to sample()
   )
  )
```

Comment: I've tried it before too, the replace = FALSE works when selecting from a column, but doesn't work on rows. I.e. 2 rows from 1 column won't be the same, but same rows can be used in other columns...